# How to format output to add a counter unix

Tags: unix, formatting, counter

```
cat new

Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as
Filer, Jack C0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab
Metro, Jim K. C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

What i am looking to do here is add a counter the idea is if the file has 100+ rows that it will be able to go until each row has been counted and that number add too it, so for example after the counter the file will look like this!

```
cat new

1  Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as
2  Filer, Jack C0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab
3  Metro, Jim K. C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` as follows:

```
awk '{printf "%d %s\n", NR, $0}' < new
```

The output is just like

```
1 Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as
2 Filer, Jack C0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab
3 Metro, Jim K. C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

EDIT:

`awk '{printf "%03d %s\n", NR-1, $0}' < new` will make the line number start from 0 as follows:

```
000 Jackson, Bob D. C0001 book pizza apple 4.00 123as
001 Filer, Jack C0002 happy apple hat 4.00 124ab
002 Metro, Jim K. C0003 kindle pizza grape 4.00 125ac
```

Comment: It worked but only when NR<=0 and NR-0! However I was curious if i wanted it to start with 000 then the next number to be 001 is this possible?

Comment: @NewEffect What do you mean by "when NR<=0 and NR-0"?

Comment: awk '{if(NR<=0) print $0; else printf "%d %s\n", NR-0, $0}'   Is the only way i could get the numbers to show up if i left it at two it would start on the 3rd record where this starts on the first not sure why on my code...

Comment: @NewEffect  Sorry, I misunderstood your meaning. I thought `cat new` was the first line of your file.

Comment: o no im sorry now it all makes sense lol its literally just showing whats in that file i guess i should have left it out side of the block of code but this definitely works perfectly thanks you!

Comment: @NewEffect edited my answer. You may write `$ cat new ` to indicate this is your command :-)